# Rationalisation Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Demonstrate by rationalizing the denominator that:

$$
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}} = \frac{(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})(a+b-c-2\sqrt{ab})}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2(ab+ac+bc)}
$$

Comment: They give you a pretty strong hint on the right side in the numerator: multiply the numerator and denominator by $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})(a+b-c-2\sqrt{ab})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}} =\frac{\sqrt a+\sqrt b-\sqrt c}{(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})(\sqrt a+\sqrt b-\sqrt c)}=\frac{\sqrt a+\sqrt b-\sqrt c}{(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)^2-(\sqrt c)^2}=\frac{\sqrt a+\sqrt b-\sqrt c}{a+b-c+2\sqrt{ab}}$$

Multiply the denominator & the numerator by $a+b-c-2\sqrt{ab}$ to get

$$\frac1{\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c}=\frac{(\sqrt a+\sqrt b-\sqrt c)(a+b-c-2\sqrt{ab})}{(a+b-c+2\sqrt{ab})(a+b-c-2\sqrt{ab})}$$

$$=\frac{(\sqrt a+\sqrt b-\sqrt c)(a+b-c-2\sqrt{ab})}{(a+b-c)^2-(2\sqrt{ab})^2}$$

$$=\frac{(\sqrt a+\sqrt b-\sqrt c)(a+b-c-2\sqrt{ab})}{a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab-2bc-2ca-4ab}=...$$

Comment: The last step was what I needed. Thanks a lot

Comment: @JuanZamora, my pleasure. Have you noticed  that $a+b-c+2\sqrt{ab}$ and $a+b-c-2\sqrt{ab}$ are basically conjugates

Answer (score 1):

Use this two equalities

$$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})=(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2-c=a+b-c+2\sqrt{ab}$$
and
$$(a+b-c+2\sqrt{ab})(a+b-c-2\sqrt{ab})=(a+b-c)^2-4ab=a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2(ab+ac+bc)$$